# How to check registering in app product at web server failed due to connection lost?

Tags: android, registration

I have implemented InApp purchases in my android app. My app flow is as follows:
1> send purchase request to goggle.
2> get the purchase receipt from google server after payment done
3> send the receipt data to my server through web service call for registration of that product on server.

Here is my question:

if step 1 and 2 are sucessfully done and while sending receipt data to my server, net connection lost then my product will not be registered on server.

In this case that product is showing unpurchased. so how to handle this?

one way that i know:
1. click on the same product again and get the purchase details from google server(without paying again) and send back to my server.

But by this way, user has to click product again and will get the feeling that he will be charged again.

So I want some thing like this:

1. A way by which, without knowing to user, the incomplete purchase who has not registered on my server side will resend the request, till then mark the purchase transction as incomplete.
2. After uninstalling and installing again, the incomplete transactions should processed for the particular user.

How to keep such records.

Comment: Please help me on the above issue.... I am still stuck up there....